# Does my solution work to determine palindrome for Linked List?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have written some code below to determine is a Linked List is a palindrome, but when I run it through tests cases it simply times out. Any idea what is wrong with the code? Thanks

```
def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
    if head == None:
        return True

    length_ll = 0
    curr = head
    while curr:
        length_ll +=1
        curr = curr.next


    mid_point = length_ll//2

    head2 = head
    for _ in range(mid_point):
        head2 = head2.next             


    prev = head2
    curr = head2
    nex = head2.next

    while nex:
        curr = nex
        curr.next = prev
        nex = nex.next
        prev = curr
    head2.next = None


    curr = head
    curr2 = head2
    
    while curr or curr2:
        if curr2.val != curr.val:
            return False
        else:
            curr = curr.next
            curr2 = curr2.next

    return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3rd `while` statement is infinite (if `curr2.val == curr.val` it will never stop)

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code above- but I am still getting timeout error? Can you suggest what is wrong and a possible solution? Thanks

Comment: Hi! Add more info: what's in you ListNode class and which tests you are trying to run